# How select multiple value in one record in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, select, where-clause

I have a table with many column. one of this contain multiple argument, How can I select a field with one of this argument. for example my query is :

```
select name from product where product='carpet' and selling='new';
```

selling column contain 'new' , 'discounted', ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the
> string list strlist consisting of N substrings. **A string list is a
> string composed of substrings separated by , characters**

```
mysql> DESCRIBE products;
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| selling | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

 
mysql> SELECT * FROM products;
+----+---------+---------------------------+
| id | product | selling                   |
+----+---------+---------------------------+
|  1 | carpet  | new,discounted,hello,worl |
|  2 | fork    | used,other                |
|  3 | plate   | new                       |
|  4 | spoon   | NULL                      |
+----+---------+---------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT * FROM products
    -> WHERE product='carpet' AND FIND_IN_SET('new', selling) <> 0;
+----+---------+---------------------------+
| id | product | selling                   |
+----+---------+---------------------------+
|  1 | carpet  | new,discounted,hello,worl |
+----+---------+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please update your answer to embed the output in text form. You can prepend it with the `>`, to apply quote formatting to results. Alternatively, sometimes code formatting needs be used. MD allows for table-like alignment of text. SO guidelines require code, data, error messages, and output to be in text form so it can easily be copy-pasted by users, and because text in images can be very difficult to read - especially on mobile devices. (Images also take more bandwidth to download.) Thank you for your thorough answer. Please consider updating so your results are more accessible by all users.

Answer (score 2):

Like @BentCoder has rightly answered, MySQL has a dedicated function `FIND_IN_SET()` that returns the field index, if the value is found in a string containing comma-separated values.

```
SELECT * FROM products where product = 'carpet' and 'new' like concat('%',selling,'%');
```

Or you could also try this by adding commas to the left and right:

```
select * from products where product= 'carpet' and CONCAT(',', selling, ',') like '%,new,%'
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for long term value. This way others can learn from your answer, and quickly see if it applies to their own issues. This keeps the value of SO high, and increases your chances of getting upvotes.

Comment: @SherylHohman thank you for pointing that out. SO needs more people like you to make people like us give a bit more ;)